# Swift - -[_UIAlertControllerAlertPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104fb1420

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, uisearchcontroller

My app is crashing on Production and I can't reproduce the error that Fabric keep sending me. There is some problem with the UISearchController, but when I use it on the app works well.
One thing I noticed is the low ram memory available at the point of this error on all the devices. It could be something related with memory leak? As more memory is needed, maybe the OS deallocates the objects and thus "unrecognized selector sent to instance", because the object that is trying to send the message (function) is already deallocated, but is a guest, I'm still facing this issue, and in my app I don't have any memory leak at this point.

The stack trace:

```
    Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

-[_UIAlertControllerAlertPresentationController adaptivePresentationController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104fb1420
 Raw Text
0
CoreFoundation  
__exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  
__methodDescriptionForSelector
3
CoreFoundation  
___forwarding___
4   CoreFoundation  
_CF_forwarding_prep_0
5
UIKit   
-[UISearchController _searchPresentationController]
6   UIKit   
-[_UISearchControllerInPlaceSearchBarAnimator animateTransition:]
7   UIKit   
__56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke
8   UIKit   
_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks
9   UIKit   
_cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks
10  UIKit   
_afterCACommitHandler
11  CoreFoundation  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
12  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopDoObservers
13  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopRun
14  CoreFoundation  
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
15  GraphicsServices    
GSEventRunModal
16
UIKit   
UIApplicationMain
17  *****   
MAMarketPlaceViewModel.swift line 14
main
18  libdyld.dylib   
start
```

This is how I'm using the SearchController:

```
lazy var searchController = { () -> UISearchController in

        let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        search.searchResultsUpdater = self
        search.delegate = self
        search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        search.definesPresentationContext = true
        search.searchBar.placeholder = L10n.searchProducts
        search.searchBar.delegate = self

        return search
    }()
....
fileprivate func setupNavigationBar() {

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
            self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.Palette.intenseGray
            self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        } else {
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
            searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        }
        if self.tableView.tableHeaderView != nil {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView?.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

On the onError event of RxSwift I'm showing the AlertController, is the only place I can think I have a UISearchController and an showing an AlertController.

```
protocol MarketCartPresentable : class {
  var disposeBag : DisposeBag { get }
  func showCart()
  func present(product: MAProductMktPlace, with cart: MACarts)

}
extension MarketCartPresentable where Self : MAMainViewController, Self : MAMainViewControllerProtocol {

func showCart() {

    guard let viewModel = self.viewModel as? Buyable else { return } //We need to have a ViewModel which impements Buyable Protocol! =)

    viewModel.getCarts()
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: MACarts())
        .asObservable()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self](carts) in

            let cartViewModel = MAMktCartViewModel(cartLines: carts)
            let cartViewController = MAMktCartViewController(_associatedViewModel: cartViewModel)
            let cartNavController = MACheckoutNavigationController(rootViewController: cartViewController)
            self?.present(cartNavController, animated: true, completion: {

            })

            }, onError: { [weak self] (error) in

                guard let errorMsg = error as? MAErrorProtocol else {

                    self?.showAlertWith(title: L10n.errorTitle , message: error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                self?.showAlertWith(title: L10n.errorTitle , message: errorMsg.errorMessage)

        }).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: The `unrecognized selector` is definitely not a memory leak. Where do you show an alert (`UIAlertController`)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're declaring `searchController` as `lazy`?

Comment: I'm presenting a UIAlertController from an UIViewController extension: `func showAlertWith(title: String, message: String) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let actionOk = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in })
        
        alert.addAction(actionOk)        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }`

Comment: Also, I'm presenting an alert if something goes wrong with a network request, but the way I'm showing it, is on a function inside a protocol extension implementation, and referencing the ViewController with [weak self] because is in a closure held by the ViewController.

Comment: I've updated my question with more data

Comment: I faced with the same problem, did you fixed it?